# Doctrine 1 allowing SQL Injection?

Tags: doctrine, sql-injection, doctrine-1.2

I found this code on a legacy app:

```
$salt = $this->generateSalt();
$new_pass_update = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->update('User')
  ->set('password', '"'. $this->hash($newPass, $salt) .'"')
  ->set('salt', "sleep(10)")    // $salt)  <- I replaced this
  ->where('email = ?', array($mail))
  ->getDql();                
die($new_pass_update);
```

I was shocked to see this Dql generated as output:

```
UPDATE User SET password = "3dbe00a167653a1aaee01d93e77e730e" 
salt = sleep(10) WHERE email = ?
```

First of all, I didn't expect to see the quotation marks around the password value.  I thougt that Doctrine would do that for me, so I tried the second argument without them, but I was shocked to see this Dql generated as output:

```
UPDATE User SET password = "3dbe00a167653a1aaee01d93e77e730e" 
salt = sleep(10) WHERE email = ?
```

If I change ->getDql() for -> execute() that's exactly the query that is executed and the db sleeps for 10 seconds.

Why is doctrine behaving like this?

Comment: I think you’re supposed to pass the value as third parameter: `set('salt', '?', "sleep(10)")`.

Comment: Wow, nice catch.  Can you please post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gumbo pointed out, the right API to use with Doctrine 1.* update syntax is:

```
$new_pass_update = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->update('User')
  ->set('password', "?", $this->hash($newPass, $salt))
  ->set('salt', "?", $salt)
  ->where('email = ?', array($mail))
  ->execute();
```

so, the second argument should be "?" and the third one, the associated value.